# Submenu disappearing when hover away from parent (css)

Tags: css, navigation, submenu

Currently, the submenu on my site disappears when I hover off of the parent (see nav menu at www.fitnessdelicious.com). I've tried several stated solutions from other threads, but nothing has seemed to work so far. I have some idea of what I'm doing html- and CSS-wise, but am now honestly at a loss as to how to proceed. Please help? CSS snippet below. Thanks!

```css
/* Navigation Menu
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
#mainnav-icon {
 display: none;
}
#navi-wrap {
 background: #fff;
}
#mainnav-menu {
 list-style-type: none;
 list-style-position: outside;
 text-align:left;
   border-top: 1px solid #eceece;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e9bf;
   z-index:100;
   position:relative;
}
#mainnav-menu li{
 float:center;
 position:relative;
 margin-right: 1px;display:inline;
}
#mainnav-menu a {
 display: block;
 padding: .15em;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; 
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
 transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
}
#mainnav-menu a:link, #mainnav-menu a:visited {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; 
   font-size:14px;
   font-weight: 300;
   color:#d2da58;
   letter-spacing:2px;
   text-transform:uppercase;
   margin:0 13px;
   height:50px;
   line-height:50px;display:inline;
}
#mainnav-menu a:hover {
 background: #fff;
 color: #ff7a7f;
}

/* Drop-down Menu
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

#mainnav-menu ul {
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
 z-index: 99;
 left: -9999px;
 background: #fff;
 box-shadow: 0 0 2px #444;display:inline;
}
#mainnav-menu ul li{
 margin: 0;
 display: inline;
}
#mainnav-menu ul a {
 width: 250px;
 width: 16rem;
 padding: 1em;

 font-weight: normal;
 color: #333;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#mainnav-menu ul a:link, #mainnav-menu ul a:visited{
 color: #333;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#mainnav-menu ul a:hover {
 color: #fff;
 background: #e84747;
}
#mainnav-menu li ul ul {
 margin-left: 250px;
 margin-left: 16rem;
}
#mainnav-menu li:hover ul ul, #mainnav-menu li:hover ul ul ul, #mainnav-menu li:hover ul ul ul ul{
 display:none; left: 0;
}
#mainnav-menu li:hover ul, #mainnav-menu li li:hover ul, #mainnav-menu li li li:hover ul, #mainnav-menu li li li li:hover ul{
 display: block; left: 0;
}
#mainnav-menu li.current_page_item a, #mainnav-menu li.current-menu-item a {
 text-decoration: none; color: #ff7a7f;
}
#mainnav-menu li.current_page_item ul li a, #mainnav-menu li.current-menu-item ul li a{
 text-decoration: none; color: #ff7a7f;
}
#mainnav-menu ul li.current_page_item a, #mainnav-menu ul li.current-menu-item a {
 text-decoration: none; color: #ff7a7f;
}
#mainnav-menu ul li.current_page_item ul li a, #mainnav-menu ul li.current-menu-item ul li a{
 text-decoration: none; color: #ff7a7f;
}
```

```html
 <div id="navi-wrap">
  <nav id="mainnav" class="container clearfix" role="navigation">
   <h4 id="mainnav-icon">Menu</h4>
   <ul id="mainnav-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-24 current_page_item menu-item-25"><a href="http://www.fitnessdelicious.com/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-13"><a href="http://www.fitnessdelicious.com/recipes/">Recipes</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-41"><a href="http://www.fitnessdelicious.com/diet/">Diet deliciously</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-86" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-86"><a href="http://www.fitnessdelicious.com/the-method/">The Method</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-90" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-90"><a href="http://www.fitnessdelicious.com/the-tools/">The Tools</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-16"><a href="http://www.fitnessdelicious.com/sample-page/">Boutique</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-54" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-54"><a href="http://www.fitnessdelicious.com/active-living/">Active Living</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-44" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-44"><a href="http://www.fitnessdelicious.com/aging/">Youthful Aging</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-50" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-50"><a href="http://www.fitnessdelicious.com/about/">About</a></li>
</ul>  </nav>
```

Comment: Please share basic relevant code. Include html alongwith css

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've copied over some html. Furthermore, I ran the snippet via stackoverflow and didn't experience the problem of the disappearing submenu. However, I continue to experience this on my site (no changes yet). Any thoughts or ideas as to how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Added an answer. Please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
/* Navigation Menu
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
#mainnav-icon {
 display: none;
}
#navi-wrap {
 background: #fff;
}
#mainnav-menu {
 list-style-type: none;
 list-style-position: outside;
 text-align:left;
   border-top: 1px solid #eceece;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e9bf;
   z-index:100;
   position:relative;
}
#mainnav-menu li{
 float:center;
 position:relative;
 margin-right: 1px;display:inline;
}
#mainnav-menu a {
 display: block;
 padding: .15em;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; 
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
 transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
}
#mainnav-menu a:link, #mainnav-menu a:visited {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; 
   font-size:14px;
   font-weight: 300;
   color:#d2da58;
   letter-spacing:2px;
   text-transform:uppercase;
   margin:0 13px;
   height:50px;
   line-height:50px;display:inline-block;
}
#mainnav-menu a:hover {
 background: #fff;
 color: #ff7a7f;
}

/* Drop-down Menu
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

#mainnav-menu ul {
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
 z-index: 99;
 left: -9999px;
 background: #fff;
 box-shadow: 0 0 2px #444;display:inline;
}
#mainnav-menu ul li{
 margin: 0;
 display: inline;
}
#mainnav-menu ul a {
 width: 250px;
 width: 16rem;
 padding: 1em;
    display:inline;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #333;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#mainnav-menu ul a:link, #mainnav-menu ul a:visited{
 color: #333;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 text-decoration: none;
  display:inline-block;
  
}
#mainnav-menu ul a:hover {
 color: #fff;
 background: #e84747;
}
#mainnav-menu li ul ul {
 margin-left: 250px;
 margin-left: 16rem;
}
#mainnav-menu li:hover ul ul, #mainnav-menu li:hover ul ul ul, #mainnav-menu li:hover ul ul ul ul{
 display:none; left: 0;
}
#mainnav-menu li:hover ul, #mainnav-menu li li:hover ul, #mainnav-menu li li li:hover ul, #mainnav-menu li li li li:hover ul{
 display: block; left: 0;
}
#mainnav-menu li.current_page_item a, #mainnav-menu li.current-menu-item a {
 text-decoration: none; color: #ff7a7f;
}
#mainnav-menu li.current_page_item ul li a, #mainnav-menu li.current-menu-item ul li a{
 text-decoration: none; color: #ff7a7f;
}
#mainnav-menu ul li.current_page_item a, #mainnav-menu ul li.current-menu-item a {
 text-decoration: none; color: #ff7a7f;
}
#mainnav-menu ul li.current_page_item ul li a, #mainnav-menu ul li.current-menu-item ul li a{
 text-decoration: none; color: #ff7a7f;
}
```

```html
<div id="navi-wrap">
  <nav id="mainnav" class="container clearfix" role="navigation">
   <h4 id="mainnav-icon">Menu</h4>
   <ul id="mainnav-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-24 current_page_item menu-item-25"><a href="http://www.fitnessdelicious.com/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-13"><a href="http://www.fitnessdelicious.com/recipes/">Recipes</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-41"><a href="http://www.fitnessdelicious.com/diet/">Diet deliciously</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-86" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-86"><a href="http://www.fitnessdelicious.com/the-method/">The Method</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-90" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-90"><a href="http://www.fitnessdelicious.com/the-tools/">The Tools</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-16"><a href="http://www.fitnessdelicious.com/sample-page/">Boutique</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-54" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-54"><a href="http://www.fitnessdelicious.com/active-living/">Active Living</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-44" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-44"><a href="http://www.fitnessdelicious.com/aging/">Youthful Aging</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-50" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-50"><a href="http://www.fitnessdelicious.com/about/">About</a></li>
</ul>  </nav>
```

i added css class ...it works.

```
#mainnav-menu a:link, #mainnav-menu a:visited{
display:inline-block !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of answering it for you, I'll point you to where you can find your answers like this going forward. Open the developer panel in Chrome (Command Shift I) on a mac, then right click the menu bar you are confused about and select "Inspect Element".

You'll see the elements on your page, and for each selected element you'll see the styles being applied to it in the styles tab.

As an example:
Just a quick glance at yours, I see a color being applied to the nav-icon class of white. When I click to disable it, I see the rest of the text appear in black. So it's there, now you need to find where the red color is being set. Look in the elements list and style tab and you'll find it.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to reply. I inspected the element and ran the code snippet via stackoverflow. Interestingly, I don't have the problem of the disappearing submenu on stackoverflow, only on my actual site. Any idea why that might be?

Answer (score 0):

try this js fiddle code:
http://jsfiddle.net/mf3y6Lj6/2/

```
Its examples, you can follow this structure for the same
```

Comment: I ended up using the inline-block change, but definitely looked into this. Thanks, anji!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a before or after pseudo element to create some transparent padding. This way you can extend the length of the item.